# Are violations of realism the same thing as contextuality?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, bells-inequality, foundations, non-locality

I am basically looking for a **counter-example** where we'd get contextuality but not violations of realism (and vice-versa). If no such counter-examples exist, then it seems to me that they're really one and the same concept.

By contextuality, I mean:

> If $A$ and $B$ commute, and $A$ and $C$ commute, then the statistics of $A$ should be the same regardless of whether it is measured together with $B$ xor with $C$.

By violation of realism, I mean:

> If we assume that the attributes $a_n$ of a system take on values $v(a_n)$ according to some pre-determined, joint-probability distribution $P$, then any measurement or combination of measurements which can't be back-traced to $P$ is deemed to be *unreal* (in the [EPR sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPR_paradox)).